# How to Disable Charles Tracking in my iOS App?

Tags: ios, security, charles-proxy

Currently, I am doing POC for Data Security.

If the iOS Device connected through Charles Proxy, the username and password are tracking in Charles Log. I don't want to Allow Charles to track requests and responses through my App like other Banking Apps. How can I achieve that?

is that possible from Native Side?

Comment: I think you need to implement some kinda encryption or use network call over ssl.

Comment: Use TLS and check the certificate chain and reject unknown certificates. This way the user can not insert the charles certificate in the chain.

Comment: hi Eric Aya, if you know solution give idea to implement, But don't discourage.

Comment: hi rckoenes, unknown certificate check is from Native side we can do or Service team can take care?

Comment: At least, you should not send username & password in clear text through http/https connection. The back-end API must support that as well. Then, you will have to read about how to avoid "Man in the middle" attack on mobile. Anyway, I must agree with @EricAya that when you don't have knowledges about security and doing a bank app, it's dangerous !

Comment: @Eric sure. I will tell. but for now i am doing POCs for different types of Securities. Actual project not yet started. once i complete all security tests in POC then only i can start.

Comment: I wasn't trying to discourage you, by the way. But in all seriousness, please consider handling the security part of your app to an expert - or at least do a bit of consulting with one. This is a banking app, people's money and data is at stake, don't take it lightly. That was the meaning of my comment...

Comment: @Eric . the app not at started. doing POCs only. so its not a problem